# What are pros/cons of hand-off from Figma to Zeplin?

Tags: hand-off

I've historically worked in a less structured environment, with XD files passed to developers and nothing more, so I'm new with Figma at my new company, and want an efficient workflow.

I'm researching how to hand-off to mobile app developers in iOS and Android, by either importing to Zeplin or just using Figma. Much of my web research shows outdated answers, before Figma made improvements -- or clearly marketing-focused answers. I want honest and current answers.

What features does Zeplin contain that Figma does not provide for code hand-off and developer usage?